# How can I find what records are not on a table?

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi everyone newbie over here so hopefully someone can help me out. I have a list that provides me with the w.id but some of the people on that list are not in our system. I’m trying to find a query that will allow me to see which w.id doesn’t have a matching p.id. I’m using Oracle SQL Developer and below is the query that I currently use. The issue is that when I run it will only bring back the records of people that are in our system which makes it hard for me to know which w.id does not have a  matching p.id. I thought maybe creating a temporary table with the w.id numbers but one I have no clue how to do this, two so far it looks like it would be time consuming since I would have to build one each time a get the report cause the list changes and the list has over 200 w.id. As I said I’m a newbie so I will appreciate if you can explain your recommendations. Thank you in advance!

```
Select p.id,w.id,p.frst,p.lst,w.stat

From worker w, person p

Where p.id=w.id
```

And w.id in ‘1000’, ‘2000’,’3000’,’4000’,’5000’

I need the results to look something like this

```
p.id     w.id    p.frst    p.lst     w.stat

585985  1000      Abigail   Brown     A

909685  2000      Frank     Thomas    I

NULL    3000      NULL       NULL     NULL

858668  4000      Lauren     Boss      A

Null    5000       Null      Null     Null
```

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, _and easier to convert to outer join_ if needed!

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
Select p.id, w.id, p.frst, p.lst, w.stat
From worker w left join
     person p
     on p.id = w.id
where w.id in (1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000);
```

If you want to bring back values that are not in the tables, then you need to construct a table in the query.  For your data, you can do:

```
Select p.id, i.id, p.frst, p.lst, w.stat
From (select 1000 as id from dual union all
      select 2000 as id from dual union all
      select 3000 as id from dual union all
      select 4000 as id from dual union all
      select 5000 as id from dual
     ) i left join
     worker w
     on w.id = i.id left join
     person p
     on p.id = w.id;
```

You might have other ways of bringing in the ids.  For instance, they might already be in a table.

Comment: Would this work even if the w.id numbers don’t exist in the tables? I get the w.I.d numbers from a spreadsheet and what I’m trying to get is which ones are not in our system so I can highlight them on my spreadsheet report.

Comment: Thanks! Your second suggestion worked for me… however I was hoping to find a less time consuming way of doing it… sadly my report has more than 200 id and putting one by one will not be very efficient but I can def use this method for shorter reports

Comment: @Ady1616 . . . If you have the ids you are looking for in a table, then use that instead of an explicit list.  There are other ways to generate an explicit list as well.  I just used this form because it is simple to follow.